# How to mock nestjs controller when it include a service with InjectRepository

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

im new to nestjs, but the mocking framework make me hard to perform tdd testing

here is my service

```
import { MyEntity } from 'src/data/entities/my.entity';
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
@Injectable()
export class MyService implements OnModuleInit {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(MyEntity)
        private repo: Repository<MyEntity>
    ) { }

    async dosth(input: string): Promise<string> {
        return Promise.resolve("do sth");
    }

    onModuleInit() {

    }
}
```

here is my controller

```
import { MyService } from 'src/services/my.service';
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiOperation, ApiResponse } from '@nestjs/swagger';

@Controller('mycontroller')
export class MyController {
    constructor(private readonly myservice: MyService) {
    }
    @Post('/')
    @ApiOperation({
        summary: 'do sth',
    })
    @ApiResponse({
        status: 201,
        type: String
    })
    async doSth(@Body() input: { name: string }): Promise<String> {
        return this.myservice.dosth(input.name);
    }
}
```

here is my module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { MyEntity } from 'src/data/entities/my.entity';
import { MyController } from 'src/controllers/my.controller';
import { MyService } from 'src/services/my.service';
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([MyEntity])],
  controllers: [MyController],
  providers: [MyService],
  exports: [MyService],
})
export class MyModule { }
```

here is my test and mock

```
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { MyController } from 'src/controllers/My.controller';
import { MyService } from 'src/services/my.service';

describe('MyController', () => {
  let controller: MyController;
  let myService = { dosth: async (input: string) => Promise.resolve("string") };
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [MyController],
      providers: [MyService],
    }).overrideProvider(MyService)
      .useValue(myService)
      .compile();
    controller = moduleRef.get<MyController>(MyController);
  });

  describe('addCompany', () => {
    it('should return company', async () => {
      expect("OK").toBe("OK")
    }
    );
  });
});
```

im running node 14.19, and

```
 "@nestjs/common": "^8.2.3",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.2.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.2.3",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^1.0.2",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.1.5",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.3",
```

i got this error when running jest src --watch

```
 FAIL  src/controllers/My.controller.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

       6 | export class MyService implements OnModuleInit {
       7 |     constructor(
    >  8 |         @InjectRepository(MyEntity)
         |                          ^
       9 |         private repo: Repository<MyEntity>
      10 |     ) { }
      11 |

      at getRepositoryToken (node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/common/typeorm.utils.js:23:27)
      at InjectRepository (node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/common/typeorm.decorators.js:7:156)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/services/my.service.ts:8:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/controllers/My.controller.ts:1:1)

                   ^
```

as you see, i even not yet to interact with the myservice class, but it seem it will new the instance of myservice when import it , any idea for how to solve it

it sounds like the issue same as https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/issues/321, but i cant change the path to relative

Answer (score 0):

you can learn about typescript decorators here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Change that line to

```
@InjectRepository(MyEntity) private entityRepository: any
```

like the NestJS docs shows:

[image]

Comment: Yup, sorry, i just typo, becoz i try to mock the code in stackoverflow, sometypo misstake

Comment: oh didn't notice that that error msg was not on this. That `TypeError` in that line doesn't make sense to me